# Why some values recognized as a date?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script to replace dots with commas in a single column in Google Sheets. 
[image: In my case its column B]

```js
function checkItNow(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('TESTSCRIPTS');
  let rangeReplace = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow());
  let valsReplace = rangeReplace.getValues().map(a => a[0]);  
  let newVals = valsReplace.map(dots => dots.toString().replace('\.', '\,'));
  let newValsArr = [];
      for (i = 0; i < newVals.length; i++) {
      newValsArr.push([newVals[i]]);
      };
  Logger.log(newVals)
  Logger.log(newValsArr)
  sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow()).setValues(newValsArr);

};
```

Sometimes after script running I'm getting dates
[image: In this case most values replaced correct but several was recognized as dates]

Why its happened? Where I'm wrong? And how to fix it?

Comment: Set the column format to float.

Comment: or plain text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default format is automatic which means that the spreadsheet tries to figure out what the format is for you.  But yes your right sometimes it gets the wrong answer.  I often use the below function to take a look at the active range formats so that I can figure out what the current numberFormat is.  The function also allows you to set in new numberFormats if you wish.  To use it all your have to do is select the range of cells that you wish to view formats for.  Note: it's doesn't handle non contiguous cell selections.  That's left as an exercise for the reader.

```
function getandSetActiveRangeFormats() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  var fA=rg.getNumberFormats();
  var html='<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>Item</th><th>A1 Notation</th><th>Number Format</th><th>Enter Format</th><th>Set Format</th></tr>';
  var item=1;
  var row=rg.getRow();
  var col=rg.getColumn();
  fA.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      var txt=Utilities.formatString('<input type="text" id="RC-%s-%s" />',row+i,col+j);
      var btn=Utilities.formatString('<input type="button" value="Set Form" onClick="setFormat(%s,%s);" />',row+i,col+j);
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',item++,sh.getRange(row + i,col + j).getA1Notation(),fA[i][j],txt,btn);
    });
  });
  html+='</table><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  html+='<script>function setFormat(row,col){var f=document.getElementById("RC-"+row+"-"+col).value;google.script.run.setFormat(row,col,f);}</script>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(Utilities.formatString(html));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, "Display and Set Active Range Formats")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found more easy solution `.setNumberFormat` from Google Apps Script

```js
function checkItNow(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('TESTSCRIPTS');
  let rangeReplace = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow());
  rangeReplace.setNumberFormat('#,##.000');
  let valsReplace = rangeReplace.getValues().map(a => a[0]);  
  let newVals = valsReplace.map(dots => dots.toString().replace('\.', '\,'));
  let newValsArr = [];
      for (i = 0; i < newVals.length; i++) {
      newValsArr.push([newVals[i]]);
      };
  Logger.log(newVals)
  Logger.log(newValsArr)
  sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow()).setValues(newValsArr);

};
```